# Embed 2D labelled array in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do operations on a dataframe but I cannot seem to reformat it in the way that I want.

I have:

```
>>df = pd.DataFrame({
'person':['Al','Al','Bob','Bob','Bob','Sue','Sue'],
'pet':['Cat','Dog','Fish','Fish','Zebra','Fish','Dog']})
>>df
  person   pet
0     Al   Cat
1     Al   Dog
2    Bob   Fish
3    Bob   Fish
4    Bob   Zebra
5    Sue   Fish
6    Sue   Dog
```

I want to aggregate to the person level and have nested labels like so:

```
   person  pet_info
           pet    number
0  Al      Cat    1
           Dog    1
1  Bob     Fish   2  
           Zebra  1
....
```

such that there are two labels/column names within the pet_info column so that:

```
 for row in df:
   print(row['person'])
   for stuff in row['pet_info']:
        print(stuff['pet'])
```

will output:

```
Al
Cat
Dog
Bob
Fish
...
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I can't seem to implement this change in this way and I am reasonably familiar with pandas...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple `groupby` + `count`/`size` should do it.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['person', 'pet']).pet.count()\
               .to_frame('number').reset_index(level=1)

df2

          pet  number
person               
Al        Cat       1
Al        Dog       1
Bob      Fish       2
Bob     Zebra       1
Sue       Dog       1
Sue      Fish       1
```

Now, assign a `MultiIndex` to `df2.columns`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['pet_info'], df2.columns])
df2.columns = idx
df2 = df2.reset_index()

df2

  person pet_info       
              pet number
0     Al      Cat      1
1     Al      Dog      1
2    Bob     Fish      2
3    Bob    Zebra      1
4    Sue      Dog      1
5    Sue     Fish      1
```

Now, you can index into each level with `df2['pet_info']['pet']`. If you want the output as in your question, you can't escape the `groupby`:

```
for n, g in df2.groupby('person'):
     print(n)
     for p in g.pet_info.pet:
         print(p)

Al
Cat
Dog
Bob
Fish
Zebra
Sue
Dog
Fish
```

Comment: That would multiindex by person - pet combinations, but I am want to be able to access the data differently, like in the for loop that I have detailed above

Comment: @T.Kevin Run this code, assign the result to, say, `r`, and then do `r.index.levels[1]`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I do not believe so. This multi-indexes the dataframe in person-pet combinations. In the above question, I need to structure the data in a different way such that for a row, row['pet_info'] returns pet, number, such that for the sublist, stuff['pet'] would return cat. The hard part of this problem isn't the aggregation or the grouping, but being able to access the data in the specific way like in the for loop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry. This would then index by person. To hopefully make it a bit clearer, I clarified how I want to access data above in the for loop. Does that loop make sense?

Comment: @T.Kevin Okay, what you are trying to achieve isn't possible to my knowledge. You want a _tree_ (hierarchical structure). pandas dataframes are _flat_, and panel like. Think about this.

Comment: Made an edit to hopefully be clearer with what I am trying to do, but I will look up trees now, thanks for the help/persistence!

Comment: @T.Kevin I'm telling you that what you're asking for isn't possible with pandas, and that this is the closest you're going to get, most likely.